# how to fixed parallax footer with Using HTML and CSS or JavaScript

Tags: html, css, parallax

How to make parallax footer, that was fixed in footer area.. 
with background image.. and it was fixed on background

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;  
  padding-left: 50px;
  background: #4B466F;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #F56469;
}
```

Comment: please explain more

Answer (score -1):

Id normally do something like this:

```
html {min-height: 100%;position: relative;}
body {margin-bottom: 130px;}
.footer{bottom: 0;height: 130px;position: absolute;}
```

Obviously my footer is called .footer.

This will give you a sticky footer.